# How can I emulate a CiviDiscount when using Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: webform-civicrm, cividiscount, discounts

I want the user to be able to type a Discount code into a field and then I want that Discount code (if applied correctly) to result in a reduction of their Membership Fees;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is easy to configure with webform civicrm (a Drupal module) - here are the steps:

**A. Create a native webform field - call it Discount Code.** Let's put it at the top - where we're going to select the Membership Type:

[image]

**B. Go to your CiviCRM Tab -> then to Memberships -> and hit the checkbox on Membership Fee;** this will expose it to the webform;

**C. String it together with Conditionals:** in your Webform Tab -> hit Conditionals
Here's mine:[image]

**D. Let's test the Form:** here are the three scenarios:

**Select Professional Membership - we don't have a Discount Code:**

[image]

**Select Student Membership - we don't have a Discount Code:**

[image]

**Select Student Membership - and we have a Discount Code:**

[image]

Comment: Thoughts on using this to reduce the cost to a 'free' ($0) registration? I've tried it with conditionals, which does zero the fee, however I run into an issue when the webform is still wanting credit card info entered to complete the registration.

Comment: Hey Jason - email me the form url and I’ll have a look

Comment: Thanks Karin. This actually makes CiviDiscount useless :-)

Comment: Combine this with webform_calculator module and you’ll be flying :-) PS if you do - we have an improved version of it that does math over multiple forms. Ping me if you’re interested.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the suggestion below from KarinG to manage a larger list of Discount codes effectively.

[image]

Comment: HI Zachary -> if you are on D9 you can use Computed TWIG fields. I've added an example to your Answer (because I can't include an image in a comment).

Comment: Zach - as your post is not an Answer it will get deleted at some point. Please either ensure you post your 'question' as a comment or as a new question. or since i see karin helpfully added images as an answer, reword your 'question' so it becomes an Answer :-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, brilliant.