# CiviCRM + Webform + Paid Events - no price displayed in table

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I'm using Webforms for events because I have a parent/carer booking up to three children onto a holiday club.

I am struggling with the price. I have a contribution page set up (I've tried with and without a price set), and I have the Participant fee exposed with the values defined (user select: 1 day, 2 days or 3 days).

When I click 'Next' to display the contribution page/table, it always says 0.00 with no row in the table to display the price of the event registration. I can't see anything similar online and I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Possibly a separate issue: I'm using PayPal Standard as the payment processor but when I 'Submit', it' doesn't go to PayPal's website to take the payment. Is it compatible yet?

If I add a 'Contribution Amount' field, it adds that to the table - in the meantime, I'm using conditionals to populate this field. I wasn't expecting to need that field.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do the pricing options for an event in Webform CiviCRM, either. I actually just posted a support request over on the Drupal issue page for the module. Hopefully one of us will get more info. The help stuff talks about a bunch of options (like checkboxes, grid, etc), but all I get is text input and select. And then all I can do is set the minimum, maximum, and steps. So if the min is $0 and the max is $350, I get 351 items in a drop down select list. Ugh!

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

ad $0 ->

- do you have the Event (in CiviCRM) configured as an is-paid event?
- are you already registered perhaps? It is clever enough to know you
  do not need to pay again. So you'll be deleting your Participant records lots when you're testing a Webform CiviCRM that has an Event enabled;

ad on building your Participant Fee ->

- create regular drupal select and/or checkboxes to gather the data you need to build the Participant Fee Then use Conditionals to say:
- if select = full day (example) and category = student -> then Participant Fee is set to: $50; 
  if select = half day (example) and category = student -> then Participant Fee is set to: $30;
  if select = half day (example) and category = regular -> then Participant Fee is set to: $90;

Key is you need to build your own Participant Fee - of course this is also what gives you huge flexibility as to what you can create.

I have some code in testing/review that will check the priceset that is configured on a contribution form in order to create lineItems with the correct price_field_value_id - that's critical financial types (and thus sales taxes to be applied properly), under some conditions. You'll know what I mean when you do encounter it yourself. It's the first bit we actually do with priceset configs in Webform CiviCRM.

What you can (recently) do is add more lineItems to a contribution [purchase calendar + make a donation scenario] - and it will create a contribution with two lineItems - priceset like. But for Event fee you can build the conditionals - and even add in discount codes - as I've illustrated here: [How can I emulate a CiviDiscount when using Webform CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/how-can-i-emulate-a-cividiscount-when-using-webform-civicrm/20729)

I hope that helps you along. If you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @karing-semper-it Thanks for the response.  
I have tried - even when the event is a paid event (and there are no participant records), I can't get the participant fee to display in the table. I've added a condition that says "if second child = yes + number of days = 1 Then participant fee = 21" but then it doesn't appear when I go to the next page on the webform with the table. 

I can only get the contribution amount (related to the contribution independently, nothing to do with the participant fee) to display in the table.

Comment: With fee = 21 -> do you mean ‘is set to’? Are there perhaps any javascript console errors in your browser that are preventing Drupal conditionals from functioning properly? We use this on numerous projects current and recent past; CiviCamp Calgary 2018 was a multiple participants for multiple event with conditionals setting participant fees webform/paid registration. Devil is in the details either on CiviCRM config or Webform side.

Comment: Yes, 'is set to'. I have other conditions that are working and that's how I have the contribution amount calculated. I can more or less do what I need as long as I ignore participant fee and just use the contribution - except it doesn't go to PayPal when I submit the form. This may be unrelated, though.

Comment: If you can post screenshots of your form and config - happy to take a look;