# Sign up for multiple events, get a discount

Tags: civievent

What is the best way to set it up so that people can register for multiple events all at once and get a discount for doing so? Say they are taking 5 trainings that are normally $100/ea and you want to allow them to sign up for all 5 at once and it only be $450?

Using Drupal 7, Civi 5.17.5

Answer (score 3):

Since you are on Drupal, you can create a webform. (You'll need the webform_civicrm module)
Enable 5 event options. Configure each event to be one of your events. Enable the participant fee field and set the price to $100.
Create a conditional 
If event 1 and event 2 and event 3 and 4 and 5 are selected then price fields are set to 90.
Enable a contribution form for online payment.

Comment: Yes that will work! I typically use user-select and thdn only enable (static) one event as an option and deselect listbox-> then you get a checkbox to register for that event.

Comment: So how do I do it if there are 10 events possible and they can, say, select 4 of them? And then those 4 are at a special price? Also, any links on doing the conditionals? I tried doing webform civi a while back and couldn't get that part to work.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. What I've done in these cases is add a checkbox 'click here if you are signing up to more than 4 events to apply the multi event discount'

Comment: You can add multiple event sets on the form -> each configured as user select so they can all become checkboxes; I’ve posted an example with a discount here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/how-can-i-emulate-a-cividiscount-when-using-webform-civicrm